# Cohesive structure of Cahiers and Dubuc topoi

Tags: topos-theory, adjoint-functors

The inclusion of commutative rings into supercommutative rings has two adjoints, one projecting out the even part and the other quotienting out the ideal generated by odd elements. After passing to opposites and sheaf topoi, this triple induces an adjoint triple between "formal smooth sets" (the Cahiers topos) and "super smooth sets".

When trying to understand the cohesive structures on these topoi, mainly following the notes "Geometry of Physics" by Schreiber, I was wondering why this triple only induces an adjoint quadruple $$\mathrm{even}\dashv\iota\dashv\Pi\dashv\mathrm{Disc}$$ through Kan extension (for example in Proposition 2.6 in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometry+of+physics+--+supergeometry). I would expect a fifth adjoint: $$\mathrm{even}\dashv\iota\dashv\Pi\dashv\mathrm{Disc}\dashv\,?$$

Is there a reason why this further adjoint does not play a role?